# Serializable isolation level - does it block read?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have read that serializable isolation level blocks only: insert, update, delete but NOT read.

I have run in one window:

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;
BEGIN TRANSACTION;  

UPDATE [dbo].[Categories]
SET name = 'aaa'
WHERE categoryid = 4;

-- without commit
```

And in the second window:

```
SELECT TOP (1000) [CategoryId]
      ,[Name]
  FROM [dbo].[Categories]
```

And the above query is waiting for the end of the first query. So does serialization isolation level block also read?

Comment: The SELECT query in `SERIALIZABLE` will be blocked if it touches uncommitted data modifications regardless of the other transaction's isolation level.

Answer (score 5):

Yes it blocks reads.  Your transaction is not committed, so you can still do a rollback.  That means the data you have updated should not be read by any other process before you commit.

Comment: Is that the same for REPEATABLE_READ? If i run select to get rows  {r1,r2,r3}, in REPEATABLE_READ isolation, is other concurent select able to execute select on the same rows  {r1,r2,r3}? I need isolation level that will block read of every row i have selected

Answer (score 1):

"does serialization isolation level block also read" : No.
Serializable acquires some lock (in Ms Sql its shared lock + range lock) which prevents writes from other transactions.
Its the UPDATE statement's exclusive lock (the above shared lock now converts to exclusive lock) that prevents second transaction's SELECT (Read Commited or Repeatable Read by deafult depending on db) to wait.